# os.walk get directory names

Tags: python, os.walk

I have such file structure:

```
d:\temp\random1\index.html
d:\temp\random2\index.html
d:\temp\random3\index.html
```

and I want to get paths to list in python. So the output would be:

```
files = ['path': 'd:\temp\random1\index.html', 'directory': 'random1']
```

I am using such code:

```
files = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('D:\\temp'):
    for fname in filenames:
        if fname.endswith(".md"):
            path = os.path.join(dirpath,fname)
            files.append({'path':path,'directory': dirpath})
```

but I cannot figure out how to get *directory* values.All I get with this code is:

```
files = ['path': 'd:\temp\random1\index.html', 'directory': 'd:\temp\random1\']
```

How to get the directory without some dirty hacks?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
dirname = dirpath.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
```